# Whitman's idea of democracy

Tags: poetry, walt-whitman

There are two lines which disturbs me a little on *One's self I sing* from Whitman. It reads:

> One's self I sing, a simple separate person,
>
> Yet utter the word Democratic, the word En-Masse.

Does it mean that behind democracy is an En-Masse behaviour?
So, he sings to a person with no face, not to a real person but to an abstract one (indeed an average one). Am I wrong?

Comment: I think that, generally, when Whitman writes "I sing X" he means "I sing _about_ X", not "I sing _to_ X".  The lines you do not quote make it clear that he interprets "self" broadly. to encompass within  himself all modern humanity.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks,  but the conclusion is the same, he sings about X as if X were everyone

Comment: I don't see this being difficult to understand: he sings of both the individual person and of the people; why on earth is that disturbing?

Comment: En-Masse because he sees the people massed together with heft and weight; and not only and simply as persons, individuals and seperate; he's saying that he emphasises *both*.

Comment: *Demos* by the way, means people.

Comment: @MoziburUllah very simple: because that person is an abstract person, which is the essence of democracy...

Comment: Whitman gave short shrift to abstract thinking, if you carry on reading; he's using 'en-masse' in a concrete manner; in the same way that Shakespeare had Hamet say 'It is a *massy* wheel, fixed on the summit of the highest mount'; it's not at all an abstract noun. It might sound like that if you're not used to the language.

Comment: Also, I think it's not correct to say that he's thinking of the people 'En-Masse' as the 'average' as you put it; because he also sees each individual too in the round, in the whole.

Comment: @MoziburUllah so he sings to what unify us? But how do you interprete * utter the word Democratic the word En Masse*?

Comment: His 'singing' is a eulogy to the self and to the people; it's generally taken that he was providing a new mythic framework for the new world in the same way that Homer did for the old world; it worked well enough that Neruda, another major American poet said that his voice was a major influence on him, see for example his *Canto General* which was his South American counterpoint to this North Anerican song. I've already answered your question in the comments above.